# Greater than is not working in CAML query

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I want to retrieve records which the users are active n last modified date is greater than lastrun date, i wrote the following CAML but doesnt seem like working. Any help is much appreciated.

```
camlQuery.ViewXml
    = "<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Active'/>"
    + "<Value Type='Boolean'> " + 1 + "</Value></Eq><Gt>"
    + "<FieldRef Name='_DCDateModified'/><Value Type='DateTime'>"
    + lastUpdate + "</Value></Gt></And></Where></Query></View>";
```

Comment: You have an extra space in the boolean specification: `... > " + 1 + "</Value...` - probably should read `... >" + 1 + "</Value...`, might be an issue?

Comment: Thanks joshcomley, but even after removing that and view n Query, it returns all the records, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it could be a Date formatting issue. You could attempt to:
1) explicit exclude of Time portion of DateTime
2) convert in advance your Date

like this:

```
...<Value IncludeTimeValue='False' Type='DateTime'>" + SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(lastUpdate) +"</Value>
```